# How do I get the value of another column on a dropdown value change?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm currently using PHP to populate an HTML table with one dropdown per row:

```
echo "  <tr>";
echo "      <td>" . $row["order_id"] . "</td>";
echo "      <td>" . $row["status_name"] . "</td>";
echo "      <td>";
echo "          <select name=\"status_dropdown\" onchange=\"handleStatusChange(this);\">";

while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    // Output the dropdown options
    echo "<option value=\"" . $row["status_id"] . "\">" . $row["name"] . "</option>";
}
```

And I have a javascript function that will fire on a value change:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleStatusChange(dropdown)
    {
    // I would like to use the Order ID value here ...
    }
</script>
```

How can I get the "order_id" value (stored in another column) from dropdown's current row? I would like to access that "order_id" value in the javascript function.

Do I need AJAX or JQuery for this?

As you can see I'm a newbie in web development :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use jquery event binding instead on `onchange`

```
$('select[name="status_dropdown"]').change(function(event){
    var $this = $(event.target);
    var orderId = $this.closest('tr').children('td:eq(0)').text()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PXfkn/)

Comment: What about the selected value of the dropdown, I tried $this.value but didn't work  :\

Comment: @user2170838 you can use `$this.val()`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need AJAX or JQuery for this (although becoming more familiar with Javascript would be a good idea) One function you could use is the

```
getElementById(id)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById

Basically you'll assign a variable in your javascript file to the object in question and then the content associated with that element can be accessed via that variable.

From the tutorial above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>getElementById example</title>
  <script>
  function changeColor(newColor) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("para1");
    elem.style.color = newColor;
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="para1">Some text here</p>
  <button onclick="changeColor('blue');">blue</button>
  <button onclick="changeColor('red');">red</button>
</body>
</html>
```